# Which tests for ordinal data (7 point scale)? Chi Test?

Tags: statistical-significance, ordinal-data, scales

I have a table as shown below. This has participants' intent to purchase a product (dependent variable) from a particular country (independent variable) on a 7 point scale (1-not likely to 7-very likely). I have put all of the data in a frequency table as below (it's just example data).

```
+-----------------+------+------+-------+--------+
|    Scale        |  US  |  UK  | Japan | France |
+-----------------+------+------+-------+--------+
| 1 - Not Likely  |  10  |  12  |   22  |   57   |
| 2               |  4   |  34  |   23  |   2    |
| 3               |  23  |  4   |   8   |   22   |
| 4 - Neutral     |  2   |  9   |   35  |   12   |
| 5               |  24  |  7   |   21  |   28   |
| 6               |  90  |  2   |   23  |   2    |
| 7 - Very Likely |  12  |  24  |   17  |   1    |
+-----------------+------+------+-------+--------+
```

I'm getting confused about which tests to conduct to determine significance on ordinal data and then which tests to show the strength of relationship. There seems to be conflicting opinions. I have run Chi Square tests and they all came back with very low numbers (e.g. > 0.000000000001). Should I be running different tests to Chi Square?

Essentially what I want to show is that, for the purchase intent rating, a product from the US is negatively (or not) affected by its country of origin.

Note: The frequency data was weighted based on actualy sample against total population.

EDIT: I believe I can use Friedman's non-parametric test. I am using XLStats for Excel. I'm not sure how to include my weighting with this.

Comment: I don't understand how you did the weighting, or why, but I suspect this may cause problems if the resultant frequency table is supposed to represent your data.

Comment: You probably don't want to use a chi-square test, because this test doesn't take into account the ordinal nature of the response variable.  That is, it knows that 1, 2, and 3 are different but it doesn't know that 3 > 2 > 1.  I don't understand entirely what you are trying to do, but ordinal regression may be an ideal approach, especially since it can account for weighting.  Traditional nonparametric tests may work, but I don't think Friedman applies in this case.

Comment: @SalMangiafico - Thank you for your help. I have since used the Friedman non-parametric test and that seems to have worked. I have also just conducted ordinal logistic regression, but my model values seem the wrong way round (I'm not sure if I am interpreting it incorrectly). For example, from visually looking at the data, I can see that Germany had the highest rated products in terms of performance, but the regression model value for Germany was the lowest -2.036, while the country with the worst rating had the highest, China is 0.000. Is China being used as a base line?

Comment: It's really difficult to answer the question in your comments, without a reproducible example and results. ... P.S. for Friedman test, what was your blocking variable?

Comment: @SalMangiafico - I'm now getting the impression that I have done the Friedman test wrong :( What would have been a better non-parametric test? Could I just run the ordinal regression without a non-parametric test? Essentially, all I want to show is that the results are significant or not and also in what direction there is a relationship between the IV (country) and DV (Likert rating).

Comment: @SalMangiafico - Is it possible for me to share my spreadsheet with you?

Comment: You wouldn't need to use both ordinal regression and a nonparametric test for this question.   Yes, I suspect there's something amiss with how you used Friedman test.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77766/discussion-between-dl1984-and-sal-mangiafico).

Comment: Yes, I will look at it, but I am certainly not equal to the collection to real statisticians and researchers collected on this site.  mangiafico@njaes.rutgers.edu